# Преобразовать SQL в ORM у Bitrix

Tags: sql, битрикс, orm

Собственно вопрос - помогите преобразовать этот запрос в ORM
задача - выбрать заказы у которых определённый статус, и пользовательское поле "Дата" будет между определённых интервалов.
В таком виде работает как надо:

```
SELECT 
`sale_internals_order_props`.`VALUE` AS `DATETIME_PLAN_CLIENT`, 
`sale_internals_order_props`.`ORDER_ID` AS `ORDER_ID`, 
`sale_internals_order`.`STATUS_ID` AS `STATUS_ID`
FROM `b_sale_order_props_value` `sale_internals_order_props`
LEFT JOIN `b_sale_order` `sale_internals_order` ON `sale_internals_order_props`.`ORDER_ID` = `sale_internals_order`.`ID`
WHERE `sale_internals_order_props`.`CODE` = 'DATETIME_PLAN_CLIENT' AND NOT `sale_internals_order_props`.`VALUE` = ''
AND STR_TO_DATE(`sale_internals_order_props`.`VALUE`, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i') > CURDATE()
AND STR_TO_DATE(`sale_internals_order_props`.`VALUE`, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i') < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND `STATUS_ID` = 'N'
```

Тут основная проблема в выражении `` STR_TO_DATE(`sale_internals_order_props`.`VALUE`, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i')  > CURDATE() ``
Как это в ORM запихать?

Answer (score 0):

[image: В ОРМ дата-время]

Может я не так что-то понимаю. Но вот в таком виде (DatetimeField) битрикс будет воспринимать дату как нужно

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа

Comment: Всё что нужно и так в тексте. А картинка для наглядности не более.